# SharePoint 2016 workflow REST API call returning nothing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a workflow and I'm trying to get simple text from another list with an API call.[image]

The request headers are: Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" and the same for Content-type.

It's returning either nothing or nothing that correlates to d/results.

When I do a postman call with the same headers to the same URL I get 2 results (as expected):

[image]

I've tried to access the same URL from the workflow server, the WFE, and the APP server and it works fine from all of these.  When I try to log the results it crashes. The server returns "OK" in the response code.

Why am I not getting any results? How can I log the results to see what's actually coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. You have to set the `RequestHeaders` here:

[image]

It doesn't automatically set that based on the variable in the text.